# Styling polygon with SLD in Geoserver

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have a PostGIS table published in Geoserver.[PostGIS table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gQ6u.png)

How can I use the "color" column to styling polygon in Geoserver by using SLD?

I try using CQL expression but not working. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Which GIS are you using? Did you publish the geometries using WFS?

Comment: Features are polygon and I have to publish it using WMS.

Comment: I solved the problem using <ogc:PropertyName>color</ogc:PropertyName>

Answer (score 0):

you can use Attribute-based line in sld styling:

```
   <FeatureTypeStyle>
     <Rule>
       <Name>local-road</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>local-road</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#009933</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
   <FeatureTypeStyle>
     <Rule>
       <Name>secondary</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>secondary</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#0055CC</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
   <FeatureTypeStyle>
     <Rule>
     <Name>highway</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Literal>highway</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
       <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#FF0000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">6</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
```

reference:

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/lines.html#example-lines-layer